# Create a Certificate for Development for iOS

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-angular, sidekick

I use NativeScript for develop on windows planform.

When I try get "Certificate for Development" by [guide](https://docs.nativescript.org/sidekick/user-guide/code-signing/code-signing-for-ios/create-development-certificate), I get this message:[image]

So, I go to "[Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/)" and dont see, how I can create "Certificates".

I want to get a certificate in order to connect the Iphone to my computer using a "sidekisk". Is it possible to get a free certificate for this? As described in the guide.

Comment: Do you have a paid apple developer account?

Comment: @DManokhin No. Without a paid account in any way?

Answer (score 1):

You must enrol for one of the paid yearly subscription Apple offers (Individual / Company / Enterprise) by producing necessary documents. Once you do, you will be given access to portal where you can create apps, certificates etc., and even publish them as long as your subscription is active.

If you just want to run the app on your own device (with limited features), you can do that for free but only if you are on a Mac with Xcode, it's all limitations from Apple itself.